# Strip away individual shape colors/styles of Visio shapes and restore to theme default?

Tags: microsoft-visio-2016

I have a Visio 2016 process flow document that someone else created. They individually set the colors (and other style attributes) for the shapes on the page. Is there any way to clear away all the individual colors/style-attributes from the objects so they'll go back to inheriting them from the current page style?

Alternatively, if Visio 2016 doesn't actually *have* a "proper" concept of inheritable styles, and changing the theme just causes Visio to rip through the existing shapes & update the color/style values that match the *previous* theme to the values associated with the *new* theme (while leaving modified values unchanged), is there some straightforward way to use a script to

- iterate through the existing shapes,
- iterate through their colors and style properties,
- compare them to what the currently-selected theme *says* they ought to be for an object of that shape type, then
- update them to match? (so the NEXT time I change the theme, they'll all go back to changing properly along with it)?